# How to be explicit in ASP.NET Controller method

Tags: c#, php, laravel, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am coming from a PHP/Laravel background and learning ASP.NET

Currently theres a lot of "magic" going on under the hood and I could use some guidance on how to work with controller methods in a less "magical" way.

Here is my current ASP.NET index method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Glassblower.ToListAsync());
        }
```

I want to do something like this php method which seems very clear in its purpose where I can call, sort, loop through, and update each record of a table in a controller method.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $hospitals = Hospital::all('name', 'id')->sortBy('name');
         return view('hospitals/index',[
             'hospitals' => $hospitals,
         ]);
    }
```

How would I call upon my glassblowers table to retrieve a collection of glassblowers sorted by a particular column and return that object as a prop to the index view?

Comment: Your question is not really specific to MVC or ASP.NET I think...you're really asking about how to run a particular database query using the ORM. So your question is actually about Entity Framework / Linq I believe. I've re-tagged it for you. Also, knowing that now you may be able to research the problem on your own more effectively. P.S. To help you, there's an Order By example on this page: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: You should read about all the [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netcore-3.1) Queryable exposes as well maybe how queries are [executed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) in entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to how to obtain an ordered list of an entity and I'll assume that you are using Linq.

Once you have your query results over the table glassblowers you could do this:

```
return listGlassBlowers.OrderBy(l => l.{ColumnName});
```